# C++-mode indenting performance depends on length of previous function?

Tags: indentation, performance

Using c++-mode in emacs23.

UPDATE:  In response to some early comments, I tested on emacs24 and emacs25, and see exactly the same behavior.  I don't have convenient access to emacs26 or emacs27 (25 is the latest version in Ubuntu Bionic LTS).

UPDATE2:  The live code in question is here:

https://github.com/jasonrohrer/OneLife/blob/master/gameSource/LivingLifePage.cpp

Grep for "dummyFunctionA" and then try adding some new blocks inside that function.  Since it's the function after the gigantic ::step function, editing it is slow.  But the next function, ::makeActive, is fast to edit.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

Got some code that looks like this:

```
void longComplicatedFunction() {
.....
}


void anotherShorterFunction() {
.....
}
```

longComplicatedFunction is 6000+ lines.  I know that sounds horrible, but it's a main game loop, and I want it that way for many good reasons (I've shipped 19 games...).  "Just split it up" would make the code harder to read in this case.  If I were going to split it up, it should be for good code/design reasons, and NOT just for "emacs reasons."

I'm finding that typing new blocks inside anotherShorterFunction is very slow, and it seems to be due to auto-indent calculations.  This struck me as strange, because anotherShorterFunction starts in the left-most column (it's a top-level block).

In fact, editing new blocks inside anotherShorterFunction is SLOWER than editing new blocks inside longComplicatedFunction.

The really interesting thing happens when I do this:

```
void longComplicatedFunction() {
.....
}


void dummyFunction() {
}


void anotherShorterFunction() {
.....
}
```

Now typing new blocks inside dummyFunction is slow, but editing anotherShorterFunction becomes fast again.

Thus, it seems like calculating indents inside a function depends on some kind of complete scan of the **previous** function?  If the previous function is short, then the indent calculation is fast.  But if the previous function is long and complicated, then indent calculation becomes slow.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?  Why should the previous top-level block matter at all, or need to be scanned, when computing indentation inside a subsequent top-level block?

Note that this is true for any sub-block of anotherShorterFunction, like this:

```
void anotherShorterFunction() {
    if( true ) {
        int x = 5;
        if( x < 10 ) {
            x = 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Creating the ( x < 10 ) block is slow if the previous top-level block is long.

And how slow?  Well, slow enough that Emacs turns the cursor into a beach-ball sometimes.

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version of emacs? The latest stable version of emacs is emacs26.

Comment: macOS is known to ship with ancient Emacs versions...

Comment: Seeing exactly the same behavior in Emacs 24.5.1, which is the standard version in Ubuntu Xenial (long-term-support).

Comment: Seeing exactly the same behavior in Emacs 25.2.2, which is the latest version available in Ubuntu Bionic (newer long-term support).

Comment: What all packages do you use for your c++ configuration? Do you have flycheck enabled? Do you observe the same when viewing the file in `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: Also, try turning off `linum-mode` if you have it on. Its known to cause problems for huge files and try turning off `font-lock-mode` and see if that improves performance

Comment: In the case of Emacs 25.2.2, this was a default, clean install of Ubuntu Bionic LTS, with "apt install emacs".  No custom configuration at all, not even a .emacs file.  I made a temporary Linode (pay-by-hour VPS) just to test this.  I'm not running "linum-mode."  Disabling font-lock-mode does not improve performance in this case.  Like I said, it's the indent calculations, not the font highlighting, that's slow.